# Syslog-ng.conf csv parser lost first columns

Tags: syslog, csv

I try to split information that come from IIS server with syslog-ng configuration. I create and fill the syslog-ng.conf but my csv parser lost the first column. let see:

```
source s_network {
        udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};

template test {
        template("test arg1 = $VALUE1 arg2 = $VALUE2 arg3 = $VALUE3\n");
        template_escape(yes);
};

destination d_file {
            file("/var/log/me.log" template(test));
};

parser testpars {
        csv-parser(columns("VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3")
        flags(escape-double-char, strip-whitespace)
        delimiters(" ")
        quote-pairs('""<>[]'));
};

log {
    source(s_network);
    parser(testpars);
    destination(d_file);
};
```

I send a test message with netcat using:

```
nc  -w0 -u 127.0.0.1 514 <<< "val1 val2 val3"
```

the result in /var/log/me.log file is

```
test arg1 = val2 arg2 = val3 arg3 =
```

my Linux is REDHAT 6 and my syslog version is 3.4.1.
Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just faced same thing with `file()` source. The solution was to add `flags(no-parse)` to the source parameters. I suppose this will help for network source also.

Answer (score 0):

You start an array with 0, not with 1.

Comment: Ok but it's the same result with VALUE0 VALUE1 VALUE2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "greedy" flag ! Otherwise it does not stick the last field.

Example :
csv_parser(columns("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3") delimiters(",") flags(greedy));

More details :
http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/reference_parsers_csv.html#example_parser_greedy